# Webservices with Maven, Spring and Hibernate

Tags: web-services, hibernate, spring, maven-2, jax-ws

I am developing an application using Hibernate, Spring and JaxWS.

I was using JaxWS 2.1 and everything was running smoothly ..

I need to upgrade to JaxWS 2.2 so I could use the @XmlElement annotation to require a parameter @XmlElement(required=true) ..

So I updated my pom file

```
<!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1-1</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now I get this Error StackTrace :

```
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:166)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:94)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:258)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:338)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:201)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:505)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:253)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:124)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 7 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.hibernate.Interceptor is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.hibernate.Interceptor
        at public org.hibernate.Interceptor org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getEntityInterceptor() throws java.lang.IllegalStateException,org.springframework.beans.BeansException
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.hibernate.Interceptor does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.hibernate.Interceptor
        at public org.hibernate.Interceptor org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getEntityInterceptor() throws java.lang.IllegalStateException,org.springframework.beans.BeansException
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator
        at public org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getJdbcExceptionTranslator()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator
        at public org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getJdbcExceptionTranslator()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.hibernate.SessionFactory is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.hibernate.SessionFactory
        at public org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getSessionFactory()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.hibernate.SessionFactory does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.hibernate.SessionFactory
        at public org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getSessionFactory()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:153)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 7 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.hibernate.Interceptor is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.hibernate.Interceptor
        at public org.hibernate.Interceptor org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getEntityInterceptor() throws java.lang.IllegalStateException,org.springframework.beans.BeansException
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.hibernate.Interceptor does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.hibernate.Interceptor
        at public org.hibernate.Interceptor org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getEntityInterceptor() throws java.lang.IllegalStateException,org.springframework.beans.BeansException
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator
        at public org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getJdbcExceptionTranslator()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator
        at public org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getJdbcExceptionTranslator()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.hibernate.SessionFactory is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.hibernate.SessionFactory
        at public org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getSessionFactory()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic
org.hibernate.SessionFactory does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.hibernate.SessionFactory
        at public org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getSessionFactory()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        at public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
        at transaction.dao.AbstractSpringDao
        at transaction.dao.CardTypeDao
        at public transaction.dao.CardTypeDao transaction.logic.TransactionLogic.getCardTypeDao()
        at transaction.logic.TransactionLogic
        at public transaction.logic.TransactionLogic transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic.arg0
        at transaction.ws.jaxws.SetTransactionLogic

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:154)
    ... 34 more
```

Anyone knows notices what's wrong exactly? I am not sure why its generating so many errors even though everything works great with JaxWS 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will solve everything but I think that you'll need to place the JAX-WS and JAXB 2.2 JARs (jaxws-api.jar and jaxb-api.jar) in both your JDK's and Tomcat's endorsed folders. See:

- [2.7.1.1. Endorsed directory](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/Using_JAX_WS_2_x___Metro_1_x_2_0_with_Java_SE_6.html#Endorsed_directory)
- [Tip for using JAX-WS 2.2/ Metro 2.0 with Tomcat 6.x on JDK 6](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/325/2009/04/03/tip-using-jax-ws-22-metro-20-tomcat-6x-jdk-6)